# Setting initialValues for redux-form with material-ui won't work

Tags: redux, material-ui, redux-form, immutable.js

I wanted to make use of my redux form for updating an object, so wanted to set initialValues, I strongly doubt I am doing something wrong, but unable to figure out what is wrong.

I followed the issue in github and passed the initial values as props
https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/916#issuecomment-217437026

```
            <NoteLayout
            initialValues={values()}
            doc={this.props.Note}
            projects={this.props.ProjectSelector}
            onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
```

and my note layout is this

```
class NoteLayout extends React.Component { 
  render() {
  const {handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = this.props;
return (
  <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

          <FormSection name="base">
              <BaseBar projects={this.props.projects}/>
          </FormSection>
          <div>
              <Field
                  name="subject"
                  component={renderTextField}
                  label="subject"
              />
          </div>
          <div>
              <Field
                  name="description"
                  fullWidth={true}
                  component={renderTextField}
                  label="description"
              />
          </div>
          <div>
              <RaisedButton
                  style={style}
                  fullWidth={false}
                  primary={true}
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={pristine || submitting}>
                  Submit
              </RaisedButton>
              <RaisedButton
                  style={style}
                  fullWidth={false}
                  secondary={false}
                  type="button"
                  disabled={pristine || submitting}
                  onClick={reset}>
                  Clear Values
              </RaisedButton>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
);


}
}

NoteLayout.propTypes = {

};

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'NoteLayout',
    validate
})(NoteLayout);
```

[Props and form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LKYh.png)

Comment: I just now noted that initialValues are converted as Map when it is passed for connect(Form)..

Answer (score 0):

redux-form/immutable is the answer, I probably did not look correctly, immutable keyword helped me out.

https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1744#issuecomment-252269843